# How to test builds on iOS 5 and iOS 4 simultaneously

Tags: ios, xcode

I am creating my first iOS application and I want to test on iOS 5 and the iOS 5 simulator, but still be able to build on iOS 4, which is the OS my phone is currently running?
What is the best method to test for beta software?
Also, what is the best way to run the current Xcode alongside the Xcode beta?

Comment: iOS 5 beta questions belong on Apple's Developer Forums.

Comment: This is a more general question on how to develop for future OS releases than it is on a specific question that regards the iOS 5 beta

Comment: @alex this is perfectly valid on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's always a good idea to install the beta release of XCode along side the official release, as you can't do submissions to the app store from the beta. Specifying a different directory at installation is the easiest way to do this (There's a pull down that easily missed when it displays the list of packages to be installed). The 2 installations will co-exist happily enough. Using a convention like Developer-4.0_betaX makes it easy to spot the one you want via Spotlight.

When attempting to use any new APIs, use the #defines of the new iOS version to prevent the new APIs from causing errors in the older versions.

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_4_0 
//APIs new to iOS 4 go here, but won't complain when built using SDK < 4.0
#endif
```

Multiple devices are also advisable, as the Simulator is only a simulator and not an emulator.

Probably a good idea to have a new source control branch for this development also.

Comment: Is __IPHONE_4_0 a constant? Or how do I create preprocessors for OS versions? thanks

Comment: This is defined in Availability.h. Future releases will not be defined here, so __IPHONE_4_0 will not be defined in the 3.x SDK for example. You can find some other useful version checking macros in Availability Internal.h. Bare in mind that these are only compile time checks.

Answer (score 1):

Set the deployment target for your application's binary to **iOS 4.x** (whichever minor version you prefer), and the base SDK to **Latest iOS**.

Comment: In Xcode's project pane, go to the Targets section and Get Info for your application target. Under Configuration you should be able to find Base SDK and iOS Deployment Target. (I haven't started using Xcode 4 so I may get some section names wrong, but that should be about it.)

Answer (score 0):

Best method: Use two or more devices. IPod Touch and iPad are good choices. The simulator is fine for development, but not really adequate for testing.